# Laravel 5.2 Class 'Collective\IronQueue\IronQueueServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use the IronMQ driver in the latest version of Laravel (5.2) and am getting the below error;

> Class 'Collective\IronQueue\IronQueueServiceProvider' not found

Here is my configuration.

**composer.json:**

```
"iron-io/iron_mq": "~2.0"
```

**config/app.php:**

```
'providers' => [
    Collective\IronQueue\IronQueueServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the package. Maybe this helps You: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-ironmq-not-found?page=1

Answer (score 1):

Try to use version 3 :

```
"iron-io/iron_mq": "~3.0"
```

And don't forget to update your composer :

```
composer update
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by adding:

`"laravelcollective/iron-queue": "5.2.*"`

to composer and then running update:

`composer update`

It doesn't mention this step on the [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/iron-queue) website.